# Random variables implicit in Glivenko-Cantelli theorem

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, measure-theory, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Theorem 1 [here](https://sites.stat.washington.edu/jaw/JAW-papers/NR/jaw-gaenssler.ess.83.pdf) states $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup_x |\mathbb{F}_n(x) - F(x)| = 0$ with probability $1$, where $\mathbb{F}_n$ is the empirical distribution function of the first $n$ $X$s, which are i.i.d. and $F$ is the commmon distribution function of the $X$s.

Is it implied that $\mathbb{F}_n$ and $F(x)$ are random variables and so $|\mathbb{F}_n(x) - F(x)| = 0$ is an event?

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_n$ is random, $F$ is not, but $\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_x |\mathbb{F}_n(x) - F(x)| = 0$ is anyway an event.